# How to remove every character from a string except certain substrings (given as a list) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, loops, substring

In JavaScript, let's assume we have a string:
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

And then we have a list of substrings, say:
["dog", "brown", "The", "jumps"]

How to filter every other character from the string, but not the substrings given as the list?

So the result in this case should be: "Thebrownjumpsdog"

The first solution that came to my mind was to use a loop, and RegExp on every iteration i.e:

```
const listOfSubstrings = ["dog", "brown", "The", "jumps"];
let theString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

for (const substring of listOfSubstrings) {
  theString = theString.replace(new RegExp(`[^${substring}]`, "g"), "");
}
```

However, the if we take a closer look (or test) the code, we see and understand that there is nothing left after the loop: On every iteration everything but the current element in the list is removed. To be precise, nothing is left after the second iteration.

So, any ideas how the end result, I provided, could be achieved given the string and the list of substrings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could *match* these substrings and *join* all the matches.

```
 const result = theString.match(/(?:dog|brown|The|jumps)/g).join("");
```

See the [pattern demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9PjJp7/2) and the beneath provided stack snippet.

```js
const theString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
const listOfSubstrings = ["dog", "brown", "The", "jumps"];

// generate regex pattern from listOfSubstrings
const regex = new RegExp('(?:' + listOfSubstrings.join("|") + ')','g');

// extract and join matches
const result = theString.match(regex);

if(result) {
  console.log(result.join(""));
} else {
  console.log('No matches!');
}
```

Comment: You could probably use split with the accept regexp to get the rejected part too?

Comment: Th OP asks to filter based on a `listOfSubstrings` variable

Comment: @PeterThoeny ... the above provided solution covers exactly this requirement with a very elegant purely regex and `match` based approach. Moreover this solution is agnostic to words / word boundaries as well as any other separators.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
const listOfSubstrings = ["dog", "brown", "The", "jumps"];
let theString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

let result = "";

const theStringArray = theString.split(" ");

theStringArray.forEach(s => {
    if(listOfSubstrings.includes(s)){
        result += s;
    }
})
```

But this might be slower if your listOfSubstrings is larger. For that, you can convert your listOfSubstrings to dictionary

```
const listOfSubstrings = ["dog", "brown", "The", "jumps"];
let theString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

let result = "";

const theStringArray = theString.split(" ");

let substrings = {};

// converting array to dictionary
listOfSubstrings.forEach(e=>{
    substrings[e] = e;
})

theStringArray.forEach(s => {
    if(substrings[s] !== undefined){
        result += s;
    }
})
```

The reason why using dictionary is that checking if the key exist, works in O(1) but array.includes works in O(n).

Answer (score 2):

This solution splits the input by spaces, filters the list by words of interest, and joins it back to a string without space to get the desired result:

```js
const input = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
const listOfSubstrings = ["dog", "brown", "The", "jumps"];
let regex = new RegExp('^(' + listOfSubstrings.join('|') + ')$');
let result = input.split(' ').filter(str => regex.test(str)).join('');
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
Thebrownjumpsdog
```